# While loop only runs with System.out.println

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        playing = true;
        while (playing){

            if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Ocean")){
                chosenBlock = 0;
            }
            else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Fish")){
                chosenBlock = 1;
            }
            else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Shark")){
                chosenBlock = 2;
            }
            else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Treasure")){
                chosenBlock = 3;
            }
        }
    }
};
blockChooser = new Thread(r1);
blockChooser.run();
```

Alright. That's the code I'm using right now. The problem is that this thing only happens once, and never again, but if I were to insert System.out.println() inside the while it works just fine, however, spamming my console. What would be the smartest thing to do here? What could be the cause to this?

Comment: Are you `run()`ing a thread or `start()`ing it?

Comment: you have to set your variable playing to false at some point of your runnable

Comment: Are you sure that while is not executing over and over without the print statement?

Comment: Probably you are blocking the thread where you do changes because of the run instead of start.

Comment: Wait... I'm not all to good with java. Should I try blockChooser.start()?

Comment: Don't just try random things. Read what they do. Java has excellent documentation called `javadoc`. Look it up.

Comment: I've been looking at the documentation, but I don't seem to understand it. Sometimes you need things explained in other ways

Comment: It looks like blockChooser.run() would bring you into an infinite loop. Maybe you should provide more context. What does this thread do? What is worldBlock?

Comment: " but if I were to insert System.out.println() inside the while it works just fine" No, that is not the right analysis. The println allows you to know that the execution flow is correct, now debug the code inside the loop, until it works as expected. Watch the values of `curString` and `chosenBlock` and see what they do.

Comment: This thread is used in order to show which current "world block" I am located on. I have generated a 25x25 world. So I have all these world blocks. This is supposed to run so I can see which block I am on

Comment: Shouldn't this be handled with some kind of event listener? As in...whenever you click/move to a new "world block", the new label would update to show the correct world block.

Comment: Yup. I just realized how stupid I was. I'll be adding so it starts the thread whenever I move to a new block. I can't believe I made it this hard for myself... thanks Solace. How do I solve the question?

edit: also I'll remove the while

Comment: Are you making some kind of game with Java Swing?

Comment: Yes, I'm making a Java Swing game. Text Fish Simulator. It's a kind of text RPG with images

Comment: You don't need a thread for this. You should look into the MouseListener interface. Whenever your user clicks on a new world block, a JLabel should update. For example, each world block can be an object of World Block that extends JPanel and implements MouseListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loop is not running "just once." It's looping *infinitely*, but since you are not outputting anything or ever exiting the loop, you can't tell that. When you put in the `System.out.println(...)`, it shows you exactly that.

You need to implement a loop terminator, by somehow, at some point, setting `playing` (which would be better named as `isPlaying`) to `false`.

For example:

```
isPlaying = true;
while (isPlaying){

    if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Ocean")){
        chosenBlock = 0;
    }  else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Fish")){
        chosenBlock = 1;
    }  else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Shark")){
        chosenBlock = 2;
    }  else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Treasure")){
        chosenBlock = 3;
    }  else  {
       isPlaying = false;   //Break out of the loop!
    }
}
```

However, since you're always checking the same thing in every iteration (the `curString`-th element in the `worldBlock` array), this will *still* never exit...unless `worldBlock[curString]` happens to *not* equal ocean, fish, shark, or treasure.

Although I can only guess this, based on your limited code-sample, what I suspect is that while loop should be completely eliminated, and replaced with a simple if-else block:

```
if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Ocean")){
    chosenBlock = 0;
}  else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Fish")){
    chosenBlock = 1;
}  else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Shark")){
    chosenBlock = 2;
}  else if(worldBlock[curString].equals("Treasure")){
    chosenBlock = 3;
}
```

Give it a try. Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm doing it right now with a void that I made. It works very well. That while thing turned out to be just a hassle. Thanks!